# Trying to display a javascript calendar in a php page

Tags: php, javascript

I've been strugling to get this working.  I'm using Joomla with directphp, so in the articles I can directly type in my php code in the articles.  I got this calendar that I downloaded (http://www.rainforestnet.com/datetimepicker/datetimepicker-tutorial.htm), but It displays corectly but nothing happens when I click on the calander image/icon.

```
<head>
<script src="datetimepicker_css.js"></script>
</head>
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();
echo "</BR>";
echo "</BR>";
if ($_SESSION['authman'] || $_SESSION['authhod']) {
include 'datalogin.php';
$manid1 = $_SESSION['manid'];
if (($manid1 == 113) || ($manid1 == 114)) {
$data10 = $_SESSION['views10'];
echo $data10;

echo "<form method='post'>";

echo "<label for='demo1'>Please enter a date here </label>";
echo "<input type='Text' id='demo1' maxlength='25' size='25'/>";
echo "<img src='images2/cal.gif' onclick='javascript:NewCssCal(demo1)' style='cursor:pointer'/>";
echo "</form>";

} else {
echo "You are not authorised to view this";
}
} else {
    include 'ses_end.php';
    header('Location: http://localhost/');
}
?>
```

Comment: I assume `NewCssCal()` is a function you've defined elsewhere above this click handler?

Comment: I looked, it's in the javascirpt file, datetimepicker_css.js which is uploaded to my root.  I don't know javascript at all

Answer (score 1):

You should send a `string` to the `NewCssCal()`.

echo `NewCssCal('demo1')` instead of `NewCssCal(demo1)` and it should work.

Comment: What does it say on your browser's console ?

Comment: It's displaying the form field & the image/icon to click on so that the date picker pops up but nothing happens when I click it.

Comment: by console i mean: download Google Chrome, then press `F12`, then press on the `console` button - a `console` screen will open. Now go to your page, click on the icon and tell what is being written on the `console` screen

Comment: Ok, I used firebug as Michael explained to me:"enabling javascript debugger to support console"
"enabling javascript debugger to support JavaScriptTool"

Comment: Ok, and when you reload your page with the console open, and clicking the icon, what do you see in the console ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look in the javascript console in your browser? I'm pretty sure there is something useful (like the js script could not be loaded).

Also: you can write `onclick='NewCssCal(demo1);'` instead of  `onclick='javascript:NewCssCal(demo1)'` as the `onclick` handler is javascript already.

BTW: It's also bad style to write `echo "<img src='images2/cal.gif' onclick='javascript:NewCssCal(demo1)' style='cursor:pointer'/>";`
It's better this way: (watch the quotes)

```
echo '<img src="images2/cal.gif" onclick="NewCssCal(\'demo1\');" style="cursor:pointer"/>';
```

@Elliot B.: the js function comes from the [picker script](http://www.rainforestnet.com/datetimepicker/sample/datetimepicker_css.js) obviously

Comment: Please copy the js console output here, maybe the error you get there is useful to help you. Have you tried the whole thing in different browsers? Which browser do you use?

Comment: Hi, I tried it in ie & firefox.  Please excuse my ignorance but how do I copy the js console output?  I don't know javascirpt at all.

Comment: If you use Firefox, install firebug (http://getfirebug.com/javascript) and then use tab "console" of firebug to get the error message. You can simply copy&paste that here.

Comment: "enabling javascript debugger to support console"
"enabling javascript debugger to support JavaScriptTool"

Comment: Ok, with activated console, reload the page and click the calendar icon/button in your website. There should be an error in the console after that. It may also be useful to check the "network" tab in firebug. It is possible, that the js file is not loaded (it may be the wrong path in your code). You can check if everything gets loaded correctly in the network tab (errors are in red, status code should be 200 for ok or starting with 4 or 5 if something went wrong; like 404).

Comment: Hi, it says:  NewCssCal is not defined

Line 1

Comment: Yeah, that's what I expected :-) So your `datetimepicker_css.js` file probably doesn't get loaded from the correct location. Please check the network tab for this file and compare the location it tries to load from with the location the file IS on your server.

Comment: Hi Michael, I selected Net (I assume that is the network tab) and then switched from all to JS but could not find the NewCssCal, what does that mean, its not loading it at all?  I FTP datetimepicker_css.js to the server again but same result.

Comment: Can you post the URL of the site you are testing? Is the filename `datetimepicker_css.js` present in the source code of the html file (crtl+u in firefox)? Is there any red entry in the "all" section of the net tab?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a while I got it working as follows, I still don't understand why the other way arround does not work.:

```
<head>
<script src="datetimepicker_css.js"></script>
</head>
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['authman'] || $_SESSION['authhod']) {
include 'datalogin.php';
$manid1 = $_SESSION['manid'];
if (($manid1 == 113) || ($manid1 == 114)) {
?>
<form method="post">
<table style="width: 100%">
<tr>
<td>1st Date</td>
<td><input size="30" type="text" name="frm_1date" id="cal1"/>
<td><img src="images/cal.gif" onclick="NewCssCal('cal1');" style="cursor:pointer"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input name="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
}
} else {
echo "You are not authorised to view this";
}
} else {
include 'ses_end.php';
header('Location: http://localhost/');
}
?>
```